# compiling error in apertium language pair

Tags: nlp, apertium

I was making english-spanish language pair by following these http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/How_to_bootstrap_a_new_pair apertium instructions but after scripting pair when I go: 
`./autogen.sh --with-lang1=../apertium-en --with-lang2=../apertium-es`
 With this command I got this error, how can I solve this problem?

`configure: WARNING: apertium-en looks like an apertium dependency, but couldn't find ../apertium-en/apertium-en.pc.in -- wrong directory, or not compiled yet?
configure: error: Could not find sources dir for apertium-en (AP_SRC1="../apertium-en")`

Answer (score 2):

All the "modern" Apertium language data uses 3-letter language codes, so that should probably be [apertium-eng](https://github.com/apertium/apertium-eng).

Ensure you've checked out and configured `apertium-eng` and `apertium-spa` in the parent dir, e.g.

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/apertium/apertium-eng
git clone https://github.com/apertium/apertium-spa
for l in apertium-{eng,spa}; do ( cd "$l" && ./autogen.sh && make ); done
```

then in the pair you're making, do

```
./autogen.sh --with-lang1=../apertium-eng --with-lang2=../apertium-spa
make
```

Comment: after following your recommendations i'm getting this

modes=`xmllint --xpath '//mode[@install="yes"]/@name' modes.xml | sed 's/ *name="\([^"]*\)"/\1.mode /g'`; \
 if test -n "$modes"; then mv $modes modes/; fi
how can I solve this error it is coming after make command in pair directory and when i run test case echo house | apertium -d . eng-spa it is taking too much time but not giving answer.

Comment: but when I used `echo casa | apertium -d . spa-eng`
it gave me correct reply immediately
`house`

Comment: that message about modes isn't actually an error, if I read you correctly, just the output of a command that's running when you type `make`